# How to delete installation directory when program is uninstalled by visual studio installer project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer

I have created an installer using visual studio 2010 installer project. The program installs correctly and works fine for all the features.

But the problem is in uninstallation, when I uninstall the program it does not delete the application directory from file system but deletes the contents of it.

Suppose I am installing the program in **C:\Program Files\MyApp**, it deletes the contents of **MyApp** folder but doesn't delete the folder it self.

Any way to do this? If there is a way then how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your application create files in this directory after it's been installed? If so, you might want your app to move that user-data to a more user-data-centric location like %PROGRAMDATA% so that application files and user-data are separated.

It also helps to make sure uninstall cleans up everything, and it's easier to persist user-data across upgrades.

Relevant thread - http://www.itninja.com/question/delete-folders-after-uninstall

Comment: Did you mean putting the uninstaller in %PROGRAMDATA% or the whole application data? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I mean put any user-data generated by the installer or the application into a subdirectory of %PROGRAMDATA% so that your C:\Program Files\... path is cleanly removed during an uninstall. It also makes it easier to try to persist user-data across upgrades (since you can just leave it there instead of copying it to a temp location and copying it back later).

Comment: Let me make you more clear about my purpose. I have one installer and one uninstaller in my project. When some one tries to uninstall the program he may choose to click on that uninstaller. I just want to know where I can put that uninstaller so that the directory is cleaned during uninstallation. Please note that the uninstaller also needed to be removed.